# Can "git push -f" in some scenario create a duplicate commit?

Tags: git, jenkins, controls, version, revision

We have a build system where the integration branches are merged into master branch. I commit into origin/Branch1  which get merged into origin/master by a jenkins job. Is it possible that duplicate commits may come in origin/master in some scenario where i have used git push -f.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by duplicate? same commits two times?

Comment: yes same commit two times but with different hashes.

Comment: ok, sometimes it happens when you squash two or more commits into one and then push it to online repository. are you squashing commits before push?